# How to Retrieve query string parameters from url specified in ng-include AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a repeater div, lets say

```
<div ng-repeat =" employee in employees">
     <div data-ng-include="'./app/details/employeedetails.html?id=123'"></div>
//id will change based on employee.
</div>
```

This would call employee details controller for each employee in the employees.
I need to get the query string parameters and retrieve the details for that employee. 
If it is in route then I can use $location.search() but this doesn't cause a route change.

Comment: the path is already known to you and you can always use ng-init  in your ng-include if you want to et any scope variable available to the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dayan Moreno Leon said, you can use `ngInit` to initialize a local property and then reference that property in your `ngInclude`d template:

```
<!-- The VIEW -->
<div ng-repeat="employee in employees" ng-init="id=employee.id">
    <div ng-include="'app/details/employeedetails.html'"></div>
</div>

<!-- The TEMPLATE -->
Employee ID: {{id}}
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/ms92t/)**.